# How can I add "custom line spacing" on a toolbar in libreWriter?

Tags: libreoffice, writer

So, I have a customized toolbar in LibreWriter and I'd like to have the option of Format---> Paragraph---->Indents & Spacing tab---->Line Spacing.

Is there a way to add it? I know I can customize the toolbar and add things I wanna do, but I can only find fixed spacing options. I dont find the option of me being able to add custom size for line spacing.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer, but if you don't manage to find a solution over the next days you could try asking at [Ask LibreOffice](http://ask.libreoffice.org).